# Python система входа и регистрации с использованием текстовых файлов, нужна помощь с фиксом бага

Tags: python, регистрация, txt

Я нашел баг в программе и не знаю как его фиксить, его суть в том что при регистрации аккаунта с одним и тем же ником должно писать что такой аккаунт существует, но вся проблема в том что если есть аккаунт с именем "qwerty" то у меня при регистрации аккаунта допустим с именем "qwe" пишет что такой аккаунт уже есть, при том что его нету, но есть "qwerty".
Помогите пожалуйста с фиксом этого бага, я уже в замешательстве

```
def choices():
    print("Пожалуйста, выберите, чем бы вы хотели заняться.")
    choice = int(input("Для регистрации выберите - 1    Для входа в систему выбирете - 2 "))
    if choice == 1:
       return getdetails()
    elif choice == 2:
       return checkdetails()
    else:
       raise TypeError

def getdetails():
    print("Напишите")
    name = str(input("Логин: "))
    password = str(input("Пароль: "))
    f = open("User_Data.txt",'r')
    info = f.read()
    if name in info:
        return "Такой аккаунт уже существет. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз"
    f.close()
    f = open("User_Data.txt",'w')
    info = info + " " +name + " " + password
    f.write(info)
    print('Вы успешно зарегистрировались (не обращайте внимание на "None") ')
    

def checkdetails():
    print("Напишите")
    name = str(input("Логин: "))
    password = str(input("Пароль: "))
    f = open("User_Data.txt",'r')
    info = f.read()
    info = info.split()
    if name in info:
        index = info.index(name) + 1
        usr_password = info[index]
        if usr_password == password:
            return "Вы успешно залогинились, " + name
        else:
            return "Данные введены неверно"
    else:
        return "Данные не найдены. Пожалуйста, зарегистрируйтесь."
        


print(choices())
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку, из `f.read()` мы получаем тип `str(ing)`, то и получается, что при выражении `if name in info` мы получаем что-то типа:

```
'kek' in 'keklol rofl' # True
```

Выходит так, что вы ищите подстроку в строке.
Либо храните логины и пароли через более стойкие сепараторы по типу `;`
(По одной паре на одной строке)

То-есть:

```
f = open('User_Data.txt','a', encoding='UTF-8').write(f'{login}:{password}\n')
f.close()
```

И потом при чтении файла делайте каст в коллекцию:

```
info = open('User_Data.txt','r', encoding='UTF-8').read().split('\n')
```

Либо гуглите как все засунуть в `JSON`, а лучше в базу данных.
Для первого раза идеально подойдет SQLite3 к слову.